# Responsive Div Resize

Tags: css, html, resize

I'm new in coding and I'm stucked with a resize problem.

My header is an image with two buttons on top (which  will be the menu). I want to build a responsive template. But when I resize the window the two buttons doesn't entirelly follow the image and stays below the image.

How can I fix it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <title>My Website</title>

    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/flowtype.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">

    body {
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }

    .image-banners {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: -1;
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        width: auto\9; /* ie8 */
        top: 0em;
        left: 0em;
    }
    .banner-title {
        position: relative;
        font-family: 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
        font-size: 2em;
        text-shadow: 0.05em 0.05em black;
        color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
        top: -0.5em;
        left: 2em
    }
    nav {
        position: fixed;
        margin-top: 2.5em;
        margin-left: 23em;
        font-family: 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
        font-size: 0.5em;
        line-height: 2.6em;
    }
    .link-nav {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: rgba(215,215,215,1);
    }
    .menu-button-left {
        background: rgba(143,3,6,1);
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(143,3,6,1), rgba(120,3,6,1));
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(143,3,6,1), rgba(120,3,6,1));
        width: 15em;
        height: 2.5em;
        text-align: center;
        float: left;
        border-radius: 0.3em 0 0 0.3em;
        border-right: 0.1em solid;
        border-color: rgba(106,2,4,1);
    }
    .menu-button-left:hover {
        background: rgba(106,2,4,1);
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(106,2,4,1), rgba(90,2,4,1));
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(106,2,4,1), rgba(90,2,4,1));
    }
    .menu-button-right {
        background: rgba(143,3,6,1);
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(143,3,6,1), rgba(120,3,6,1));
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(143,3,6,1), rgba(120,3,6,1));
        width: 15em;
        height: 2.5em;
        text-align: center;
        float: left;
        border-radius: 0 0.3em 0.3em 0;
    }
    .menu-button-right:hover {
        background: rgba(106,2,4,1);
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(106,2,4,1), rgba(90,2,4,1));
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(106,2,4,1), rgba(90,2,4,1));
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <img class="image-banners" src="images/Banner.png" />
        <h1 class="banner-title body">MY WEBSITE</h1>
        <nav>
            <a class="link-nav body" href="#1"><div class="menu-button-left"><b>BUTTON 1</b></div></a>
            <a class="link-nav body" href="#2"><div class="menu-button-right"><b>BUTTON 2</b></div></a>
        </nav>
    </header>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('body').flowtype({
 minimum   : 400,
 maximum   : 1000,
 minFont   : 5,
 maxFont   : 40,
 fontRatio : 30
});
</script>

</body>
```

Thanks for you

Comment: can you provide any link?

Comment: Your buttons are in a nav which is position fixed, so they ll always stay at the top of the page. Apart from that, image is also position absolute. If you use positions better, you won't have to mind so much about responsive. Also, you have <div> inside a <a> which is invalid markup (In HTML5 it's ok but avoit it).

Comment: Dheeraj - Unfortunately I'm still quite in the begin and I'm very newbie so I'm building the website based on my pc.
Naele - Thanks for your comment I will study your advices so I can improve my html

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is common in these cases to create `jsfiddle` links or something similar to demonstrate your problem. In that case you can find one [here](http://jsfiddle.net/76Rxg/1/).

Now to add responsiveness to your buttons you need to use `media queries`. (this applies in general for the responsive design) Please have a look how to use the media queries [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) and I guess you will be ready enough to solve it.

Comment: This is really more of a comment than an answer

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Next time I'll try to be more correct using jsfiddle. I'm going to investigate what you post in here and try to fix based on it.